# set up a variable in a makefile rule to be used in another rule

Tags: compilation, makefile, avr

I'm trying to set up a Makefile so I can work the following rules out:

```
make board1 flash
```

or

```
make board2 flash
```

Where `board1` compiles a firmware for a given board and `board2` compiles a firmware for another one.

I know I could define a `flash` rule for each board, but I'm supporting a lot of boards, and I'd like to add support of a new board as simple as possible, using variables defined in rules.

So I wrote the following rule:

```
board1: MCU=atmega2560
board1: F_CPU=16000000
board1: build/main-board1.o
```

and I can compile everything perfectly well. Then I got the `flash` command to work:

```
flash:
    $(AVRDUDE) -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER) -U flash:w:build/*.hex
```

so when I execute `make board1 flash`, I'd like to have `$(MCU)` set to the `atmega2560` value.

N.B.: though I think the previous question is a possible one, I got another one, but I think that one is not possible:

```
board1: TARGET=board1
board1: build/main-$(TARGET).o

flash: build/main-$(TARGET).o
    $(AVRDUDE) ...
```

what I mean, is if there would be a way to define a variable from within the rule to be used in another rule?

Comment: as a side question, would it be possible to achieve the same result using a main makefile where I define the variables before including another makefile and call the rule within?

Comment: Yes, or you could have the rule in the main makefile, and include ancillary files that that define the variables-- that way you can include those files *conditionally*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use "make board1 flash" and "make board2 flash", but you *shouldn't*. It goes against the way Make is supposed to work. The arguments listed in the call to Make are supposed to be independent targets, not commands that modify each other.

A better way is like this:

```
make BOARD=board1 flash
```

and

```
make BOARD=board2 flash
```

(or equivalently `make flash BOARD=board1` and `make flash BOARD=board2`, the order doesn't matter), using this makefile:

```
ifeq ($(BOARD), board1)
MCU=atmega2560
F_CPU=16000000
endif

ifeq ($(BOARD), board2)
MCU=otherMCU
F_CPU=33333
endif

flash: build/main-$(BOARD).o
    $(AVRDUDE) -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER) -U flash:w:build/main-$(TARGET).hex
```

(Notice that TARGET is redundant, it's the same as BOARD.)

Answer (score 0):

ahah! Sometimes one just need to ask a question to find the answer to it the following second!

here's the answer to my own question: the `$(eval VAR=VAL)` magic does the trick.

```
board1: $(eval MCU=atmega2560)
board1: $(eval F_CPU=16000000)
board1: $(eval TARGET=board1)
board1: build/main-$(TARGET).o

flash: build/main-$(TARGET).o
    $(AVRDUDE) -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER) -U flash:w:build/main-$(TARGET).hex
```

I'm still open to suggestions and for more elegant ways to achieve the same thing, though!

Comment: This won't work. Try `make board2 flash`, and you'll see the same variable values.